# Function .get of ExifTags - What is it?

Tags: python, image, exif

I am currently working with image metadata, i.e. in Python with ExifTAGS ecc.

I have written a program that reads the information of an image that you have previously selected. Therefore I want that what is in "print" (see image (& Code-Line)) does not have to be in the program prompt box, but in the separate tkinter window.

```
print(ExifTags.TAGS[i] + " - " + str(j))
```

Code Image: [ExifTAGS.get()-function?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXVcl.jpg)

For this to happen, what is in "print" must be defined so that the program understands "take the image that is selected". What is the .get() function of ExifTags? Or should I just do print.get()? Does anyone have any idea?

I hope my request has been understood so far.
I thank you for any help.

Thanks,
PyBeginner

Comment: You dont use `print()` to show data in a tkinter window, for that you have to use `tkinter.Label`. You should probably watch a tutorial on tkinter.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Yes, yes, I know that. Only I need a get function, since it's content is never fixed but can always vary, from image to image. Therefore the question if there is a function that simply outputs ExifTags with .get(metadata of the image)

Comment: Why not read the data each time when image is changed?